# update goes into a loop shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have designed a shiny app to change the limits in y of a plot in order to visualize my data (geological time series, y being the depth/time and x any parameter) easily, centred on the y value I want. In the interface I have different input types to navigate in y, such as up and down buttons and a slider. This slider is updating itself if I use the buttons. However, if I click too fast  or if I change the slider too fast (i.e. before the plot refreshes), the app will go into a loop and oscillate between two y values.

I've tried using isolate() in different positions but without success, and cannot find how to resolve the bug.

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Here is an example, click fast on the buttons to make the bug appear;

```
library(shiny)

ymax <- 100
ymin <- 0


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(

    h3("See"),

    numericInput("yinter", "Vertical interval (m)",
                 min = 0, max = ymax, value = 50, step = 0.5),

    numericInput("movepercent", "Scroll interval (%)",
                 min = 0, max = 100, value = 15, step = 5),

    numericInput("heightNumeric", "Height (m)",
                 min = ymin, max = ymax, value = ymin, step = 1),

    sliderInput("heightSlider","Height (m)",min = ymin, max = ymax, 
                value = ymin,step=0.01),

    actionButton("up","",icon("arrow-up"),
                 width = "100%"),

    actionButton("down","",icon("arrow-down"),
                 width = "100%",""),


    width=2
  ),

  sidebarPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1",height = 800)
  )

)


server <- function(input, output, clientData, session) {


  values <- reactiveValues()

  values$i <- 0

  observeEvent(input$up, {
    values$i <- values$i + input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
  })

  observeEvent(input$down, {
    values$i <- values$i - input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightSlider, {
    values$i <- input$heightSlider
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightNumeric, {
    values$i <- input$heightNumeric
  })

  observe({
    updateNumericInput(session,"heightNumeric",value = values$i)
  })

  observe({
    updateSliderInput(session,"heightSlider",value = values$i)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(seq(from=0,to=1,by=0.0001),seq(from=0,to=100,by=0.01),
         type="l",ylim=c(values$i-input$yinter/2,
                         values$i+input$yinter/2))
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem on my pc. One thing to note is that the buttons allow you to select values outside of the slider range.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam I can actually. Just try to click as fast as possible on the buttons, and at one point it starts oscillating.

Comment: @SébastienWouters It was just something I noticed while spamming the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
library(shiny)

ymax <- 100
ymin <- 0


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(

    h3("See"),

    numericInput("yinter", "Vertical interval (m)",
                 min = 0, max = ymax, value = 50, step = 0.5),

    numericInput("movepercent", "Scroll interval (%)",
                 min = 0, max = 100, value = 15, step = 5),

    uiOutput("inputs"),

    actionButton("up","",icon("arrow-up"),
                 width = "100%"),

    actionButton("down","",icon("arrow-down"),
                 width = "100%",""),


    width=2
  ),

  sidebarPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1",height = 800)
  )

)


server <- function(input, output, clientData, session) {


  ival <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$up, {
    newval <- ival() + input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
    ival(newval)
  })

  observeEvent(input$down, {
    newval <- ival() - input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
    ival(newval)
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightSlider, {
  if(input$heightNumeric != input$heightSlider){
    ival(input$heightSlider)
  }
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightNumeric, {
  if(input$heightNumeric != input$heightSlider){
    ival(input$heightNumeric)
  }
  })

  output$inputs <- renderUI({
    newval <- ival()
    tagList(
      numericInput("heightNumeric", "Height (m)",
                   min = ymin, max = ymax, value = newval, step = 1),

      sliderInput("heightSlider","Height (m)",min = ymin, max = ymax, 
                  value = newval ,step=0.01)

    )
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(seq(from=0,to=1,by=0.0001),seq(from=0,to=100,by=0.01),
         type="l",ylim=c(ival() - input$yinter/2,
                         ival() + input$yinter/2))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? What makes this work and the others not?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to isolate your hight slider and height numeric and make it respond to clicks on the action buttons:

```
library(shiny)

ymax <- 100
ymin <- 0


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(

    h3("See"),

    numericInput("yinter", "Vertical interval (m)",
                 min = 0, max = ymax, value = 50, step = 0.5),

    numericInput("movepercent", "Scroll interval (%)",
                 min = 0, max = 100, value = 15, step = 5),

    numericInput("heightNumeric", "Height (m)",
                 min = ymin, max = ymax, value = ymin, step = 1),

    sliderInput("heightSlider","Height (m)",min = ymin, max = ymax, 
                value = ymin,step=0.01),

    actionButton("up","",icon("arrow-up"),
                 width = "100%"),

    actionButton("down","",icon("arrow-down"),
                 width = "100%",""),


    width=2
  ),

  sidebarPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1",height = 800)
  )

)


server <- function(input, output, clientData, session) {


  values <- reactiveValues(i = 0)

  values$i <- 0

  observeEvent(input$up, {
    values$i <- values$i + input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
  }, priority = 1)

  observeEvent(input$down, {
    values$i <- values$i - input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
  }, priority = 2)

  observeEvent(input$heightSlider, {
    values$i <- input$heightSlider
  }, priority = 3)

  observeEvent(input$heightNumeric, {
    values$i <- input$heightNumeric
  }, priority = 4)

  observe({
    if (input$up==0 & input$down==0) return()
    isolate({
      updateNumericInput(session,"heightNumeric",value = values$i)      
    })
  })

  observe({
    if (input$up==0 & input$down==0) return()
    isolate({
      updateSliderInput(session,"heightSlider",value = values$i)
    })
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(seq(from=0,to=1,by=0.0001),seq(from=0,to=100,by=0.01),
         type="l",ylim=c(values$i-input$yinter/2,
                         values$i+input$yinter/2))
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This indeed solves the oscillation, however it enables the update of the slider when using the numeric input and vice versa the update of the numeric input when using the slider

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to isolate anything, but you have to remove the circular dependencies in your application. Right now, you can indeed end up in an oscillation because all the updates are occuring independently. So if two inputs change `values$i` before everything is updated, you'll get a continuous oscillation between those values, as you have witnessed.

The most simple solution is to update only what needs to be updated inside every observer. So when the slider is touched, immediately update the `numericInput`. When the numeric input is touched, immediately update the `sliderInput`. When any of the buttons is pushed, update both.

This gives you the following server function. You can try what you want, as the updates are all done inside a single expression, everything is updated before shiny evaluates the next reactive in the chain.

```
server <- function(input, output, clientData, session) {


  values <- reactiveValues()

  values$i <- 0

  observeEvent(input$up, {
    values$i <- values$i + input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
    updateNumericInput(session,"heightNumeric",value = values$i)
    updateSliderInput(session,"heightSlider",value = values$i)
  })

  observeEvent(input$down, {
    values$i <- values$i - input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
    updateNumericInput(session,"heightNumeric",value = values$i)
    updateSliderInput(session,"heightSlider",value = values$i)
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightSlider, {
    values$i <- input$heightSlider
    updateNumericInput(session,"heightNumeric",value = values$i)
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightNumeric, {
    values$i <- input$heightNumeric
    updateSliderInput(session,"heightSlider",value = values$i)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(seq(from=0,to=1,by=0.0001),seq(from=0,to=100,by=0.01),
         type="l",ylim=c(values$i-input$yinter/2,
                         values$i+input$yinter/2))
  })

}
```

Comment: This solution works partly: the oscillation problem remains, but if I suppress one of the updates in the observeEvent of either the slider or the numeric input it works. In that case however only one of these two does update.

Comment: @SébastienWouters weird, I can't get it to oscillate any more and it shouldn't. I'll take another look to see if I can avoid this.

Comment: undeleted per request of OP

Answer (score 0):

I was completely wrong. The problem is indeed the asynchronous update of both the numeric and the slider input. To be more exact, the update functions (`updateSliderInput` resp `updateNumericInput` ) don't update the sliders immediately. These updates are sent to the client only after all other observers are run.

Now imagine you updated the slider. the `observeEvent` updates `ival()`. That triggers the `observer()` to update both inputs. But if you push eg the `up` button before these updates are sent to the client, `ival` changes to a new value before the old value is sent to update the inputs. That old value changes the `input$sliderInput`, which triggers the `observeEvent()` again and a new cycle begins. That's what's causing your oscillation I believe.

To solve this, you need to regenerate the input on the server side instead of updating it on the client side. Or you could avoid using 4 different inputs for the exact same thing ofcourse...

So your example app becomes:

```
library(shiny)

ymax <- 100
ymin <- 0


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(

    h3("See"),

    numericInput("yinter", "Vertical interval (m)",
                 min = 0, max = ymax, value = 50, step = 0.5),

    numericInput("movepercent", "Scroll interval (%)",
                 min = 0, max = 100, value = 15, step = 5),

    uiOutput("inputs"),

    actionButton("up","",icon("arrow-up"),
                 width = "100%"),

    actionButton("down","",icon("arrow-down"),
                 width = "100%",""),


    width=2
  ),

  sidebarPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1",height = 800)
  )

)


server <- function(input, output, clientData, session) {


  ival <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$up, {
    newval <- ival() + input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
    ival(newval)
  })

  observeEvent(input$down, {
    newval <- ival() - input$yinter*(input$movepercent/100)
    ival(newval)
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightSlider, {
    ival(input$heightSlider)
  })

  observeEvent(input$heightNumeric, {
    ival(input$heightNumeric)
  })

  output$inputs <- renderUI({
    newval <- ival()
    tagList(
      numericInput("heightNumeric", "Height (m)",
                   min = ymin, max = ymax, value = newval, step = 1),

      sliderInput("heightSlider","Height (m)",min = ymin, max = ymax, 
                  value = newval ,step=0.01)

    )
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(seq(from=0,to=1,by=0.0001),seq(from=0,to=100,by=0.01),
         type="l",ylim=c(ival() - input$yinter/2,
                         ival() + input$yinter/2))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I tried, and sadly it does not seem to work: it still oscillates

Comment: @SébastienWouters indeed, and I've been wrong a few times now :-). Turns out the problem is that the update message is always sent after all other observers are run. So you'll have to stop using the update functions and render a UI as I've shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, no problem :-) I retried this code and even if it oscillates, it stabilises after some time. Could you reupload the first solution that you had ? I had it but forgot to save it; with it the slider and buttons alone worked well. Thanks for everything :-)

Comment: @SébastienWouters that's normal, shiny has to go through a few loops before everything is updated to the new values. I personally would ditch at least one of the inputs as well. three inputs for the same thing seems a bit overkill :-)